# Number of times particle reverses direction on $s = t^5 + 5t^4$

Tags: derivatives, physics

The question I'm solving is "If a particle moves along a line according to the law $s = t^5 + 5t^4$, then the number of times it reverses direction is:" with the answers $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. I can see from the graph it reverses twice, but I'd have to solve this without a calculator for my exams.

Now according to Barron's, "If $s$ is a continuous function of $t$, the particle reverses direction whenever $v$ (velocity) is zero and a (acceleration) is NOT zero". Using this rule, I computed the velocity function as $v = 5t^4 + 20t^3$ and acceleration as $a = 20t^3 + 60t^2$.

Velocity is zero at $t = -4$, $t = 0$; however, acceleration is also $0$ at $t = 0$, yet the graph still reverses. So how would I go about solving this without graphing the original equation?

Comment: A particle can reverse the direction when both instantaneous velocity and instantaneous acceleration are $0$.  Try the $1$-dimensional trajectory $s(t)=t^4$ at $t=0$.  A better criterion would probably be $$s(t+\tau)= a+ b\,t^{2n}+o\left(t^{2n}\right)$$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $b\neq 0$, for some positive integer $n$, and for all sufficiently small $t$, then $\tau$ is a time at which the particle reverses its direction.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Don't worry about acceleration. The velocity is $5(t+4)t^3$. so the only candidates for direction reversal are $-4$ and $0$. Now we can easily find (say using test points) that there is a change of sign at $t=-4$ and also at $t=0$.  Comment: For max/min, students often show an overfondness for the second derivative test. Careful examination of the first derivative is ordinarily more useful.  Second derivative can be unpleasant to calculate and analyze.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, I'll make sure to typeset from now on.

Comment: @Batominovski How would I apply your formula to my current question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you reference, namely

> If $s$ is a continuous function of $t$, the particle reverses direction whenever $v$ (velocity) is zero and a (acceleration) is NOT zero.

is true, however, the opposite direction is not true, because it could be that it reverses direction even if velocity and acceleration are both zero. You've already seen that this problem is an example of this.

The easiest way of dealing with this issue (in most cases) is simply not to compute acceleration at all: instead, **look at where the derivative changes sign.** (Sometimes this is done by drawing a "sign line".)
The particle reverses direction *if and only if* the velocity changes sign.

In this case, we have
$$
v = 5t^3(t+4)
$$
You've observed that this is zero at $t = 0$ and $t = -4$. But does it switch sign at both these points? To find out, simply plug in some values in between and on either side
\begin{align*}
\text{At } &t = -5, v = 5(-5)^3(-5 + 4) > 0. \\
\text{At } &t = -2, v = 5(-2)^3(-2 + 4) < 0. \\
\text{At } &t = 1, v = 5(1)^3(1 + 4) > 0. \\
\end{align*}
So we have that velocity is *positive* for $t < -4$, *negative* for $-4 < t < 0$, and *positive* for $t > 0$. That means it switches sign at both $-4$ and $0$, so both of those are points where the particle reverses direction.

---

**Edit:** There's another method that works, too, called the *higher-order derivative test*. In this case, the fourth derivative of the particle's position, $120 + 120t$ is positive at $t=0$, and four is even, which means the velocity changes from negative to positive. You can read about this test [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, could one keep differentiating the equation until they get a higher derivative, let's say z(x), where z(0) is not equal to 0? For example, differentiating the acceleration to get the "jerk" still returns 0 at t = 0, but the "jounce", 120t+120, returns 120 at t = 0. 120 is positive, which I notice lines up with the velocity switching from negative to positive at t = 0. 

I definitely may be seeing something that isn't there, so I just wanted to double check.

Comment: @KartikChughヅ Yes, that's another method that works -- you have to be careful though. If an even derivative (acceleration, jounce, etc.) is not zero, then it tells you whether the particle switches direction. But if an *odd* derivative is not zero (jerk, etc.) then the particle doesn't switch direction at all.

Comment: @KartikChughヅ I added a bit about that test, called the higher-derivative test, into my answer!

Comment: So if it was an odd function, I wouldn't be able to use the higher-derivative test for a direction reversal question, right?

Comment: @KartikChughヅ It doesn't matter whether it's an odd or even function. By odd derivative, I mean a first derivative, third derivative, and so on.